# Simple Bison file does not compile

Tags: c++, bison, lex

I am new to flex and Bison. The following bison file does not compile to produce .cpp and .h files:

If I remove the code to support if statement then it works. The `|ifStmt{$$=$1;}` in the `statement:`, rule `ifStmt: TOKEN_IF expression TOKEN_DO statement TOKEN_ELSE TOKEN_DO statement{$$=makeIf($2, $3, $7);};` and change the token declaration by deleting the `TOKEN_IF` and `TOKEN_ELSE`

```
%error-verbose /* instruct bison to generate verbose error messages*/
%{
#include "astgen.h"
#define YYDEBUG 1

/* Since the parser must return the AST, it must get a parameter where
 * the AST can be stored. The type of the parameter will be void*. */
struct AstElement* astDest;
extern int yylex();
%}

%union {
    int val;
    char op;
    char* name;
    struct AstElement* ast; /* this is the new member to store AST elements */
}

%token TOKEN_BEGIN TOKEN_END TOKEN_WHILE TOKEN_DO TOKEN_IF TOKEN_ELSE
%token<name> TOKEN_ID
%token<val> TOKEN_NUMBER
%token<op> TOKEN_OPERATOR
%type<ast> program block statements statement assignment expression whileStmt call
%start program

%{
/* Forward declarations */
void yyerror(const char* const message);


%}

%%

program: statement';' { astDest = $1; };

block: TOKEN_BEGIN statements TOKEN_END{ $$ = $2; };

statements: {$$=0;}
    | statements statement ';' {$$=makeStatement($1, $2);}
    | statements block';' {$$=makeStatement($1, $2);};

statement: 
      assignment {$$=$1;}
    | whileStmt {$$=$1;}
    | ifStmt{$$=$1;}
    | block {$$=$1;}
    | call {$$=$1;}

assignment: TOKEN_ID '=' expression {$$=makeAssignment($1, $3);}

expression: TOKEN_ID {$$=makeExpByName($1);}
    | TOKEN_NUMBER {$$=makeExpByNum($1);}
    | expression TOKEN_OPERATOR expression {$$=makeExp($1, $3, $2);}

whileStmt: TOKEN_WHILE expression TOKEN_DO statement{$$=makeWhile($2, $4);};

ifStmt: TOKEN_IF expression TOKEN_DO statement TOKEN_ELSE TOKEN_DO statement{$$=makeIf($2, $4, $7);};

call: TOKEN_ID '(' expression ')' {$$=makeCall($1, $3);};

%%

#include "astexec.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

void yyerror(const char* const message)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Parse error:%s\n", message);
    exit(1);
}
```

And the lex file for the above is:

```
%option noyywrap

%{
#include "parser.tab.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
%}

%option noyywrap

%%

"while" return TOKEN_WHILE;
"{" return TOKEN_BEGIN;
"}"   return TOKEN_END;
"do"    return TOKEN_DO;
"if"    return TOKEN_IF;
"else"  return TOKEN_ELSE;
"=="    {yylval.op = *yytext; return TOKEN_OPERATOR;}
"!="    {yylval.op = *yytext; return TOKEN_OPERATOR;}
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* {yylval.name = _strdup(yytext); return TOKEN_ID;}
[-]?[0-9]+    {yylval.val = atoi(yytext); return TOKEN_NUMBER;}
[()=;]  {return *yytext;}
"<="    {yylval.op = *yytext; return TOKEN_OPERATOR;}
">="    {yylval.op = *yytext; return TOKEN_OPERATOR;}
[*/+-<>] {yylval.op = *yytext; return TOKEN_OPERATOR;}
[ \t\n] {/* suppress the output of the whitespaces from the input file to stdout */}
#.* {/* one-line comment */}

%%
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps there are some error messages that go along with the failure to compile. Maybe reading them could shed some light on the problem.

Comment: @n.m. I am using winflexbison build on a VS 2012 platform. It just skips compilation of the Bison file and throws no error at all.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the "main" error, but your token indices are wrong; they should be `$$=makeIf($2, $4, $7);`.

Comment: If your tool chain doesn't show compilation errors, it is unsuitable for anything. Solve this problem first. Use command line tools, or configure your IDE properly, or whatever. Closing as not enough information.

Comment: @Aasmund Eldhuset Thanks for pointing out, This is a typo when I posted on SO. The error was fixed by correcting declation for `%type` as mentioned in the solution below.

Comment: @Segmented: I assumed there might be a more serious error that I didn't immediately see, which is why I didn't post this as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `%type` declaration for `ifStmt`, as the error message from bison tells you:

```
t.y:46.17-18: $1 of `statement' has no declared type
t.y:58.78-79: $$ of `ifStmt' has no declared type
t.y:58.92-93: $3 of `ifStmt' has no declared type
```

Adding `ifStmt` to the declaration `%type<ast>` on line 23 will fix the first 2 errors; the third can be fixed by using `$4` instead of `$3`.